# using fastboot to flash an image on Windows remains stuck on < waiting for any device >

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, sudo, adb

I have a Linux based MCU device that's connected using USB into which I'm flashing a boot or system image using `fastboot`. On an ubuntu host machine, I use fastboot with root permissions via `sudo`

```
adb reboot bootloader
sudo fastboot flash <partition> <image>
sudo fastboot reboot
```

and it works, however when I attempt the same on Windows command line using as an admin (without `sudo` ofcourse, I don't see anything in response to `fastboot devices`

```
adb devices
// does show the device ID

adb reboot bootloader

fastboot devices 
// nothing shows up

sudo fastboot flash <partition> <image>
< waiting for device >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Update the android driver

- enter the device into fastboot mode
- download [this](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1H8DxaRta8gafcUA8bJqkajobnnfuw2et) into your local drive
- go into device manager, select the Android device in device manager
- update its driver path to that of what you just downloaded

For [reference](https://beebom.com/fastboot-not-detecting-device-windows-10/#:%7E:text=If%20ADB%20is%20working%20for,Device%20Manager%E2%80%9D%20and%20open%20it.).

Comment: It might be helpful to describe what you are linking to in your answer (for both the Google Drive link and the website link).

Answer (score -1):

I was stuck on this same problem with an nvidia shield. I cam across a few threads that stated that after a somewhat recent windows update made fastboot no longer work. IDK is thats for all devices or just for shield but ended us running a linux vm to solve my issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).